# Characterising optimal majorising Lyapunov function for Markov semigroup

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, parabolic-pde

Fix a space $\mathcal{X}$, a Markov process on that space with infinitesimal generator $L$, and a positive function $g : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbf{R}_+$. I don't want to assume too much more about the specifics of the process (e.g. ergodicity) because the specific example in which I am interested is somewhat degenerate, but I'm happy to add further details on this point if it turns out to be important.

Suppose that I want to prove that for large $t$, the expectation $\mathbf{E} \left[ g(X_t) \mid X_0 = x \right]$ decays to $0$ like $\exp(-ct)$, for some $c > 0$. One approach to this would be to identify a function $f \geqslant g$ such that $Lf \leqslant - cf$, as (subject to suitable regularity, etc.) this would directly imply that $\mathbf{E} \left[ f(X_t) \mid X_0 = x \right] \leqslant f(x) \cdot \exp(-ct)$, and hence that $\mathbf{E} \left[ g(X_t) \mid X_0 = x \right] \leqslant f(x) \cdot \exp(-ct)$, from which the desired result would follow.

**My interest** then lies in identifying the minimal such $f$, in a suitable sense.

1. As a zeroth component, I concede that I'm not entirely sure how to specify the nature of the minimality desideratum (e.g. does it make sense to ask for pointwise minimality?). Perhaps there's not even necessarily a 'right' answer to this clause, but I wanted to flag that I'm a bit stumped on this point, either way.
2. As the 'real' question, I want to know whether there is a concise description of $f$ in terms of something like e.g. the Feynman-Kac formula, or the solution to the Poisson equation - something involving expectations under the Markov semigroup, and maybe integrating over time in some sense. A formulation involving some sort of stochastic control problem would presumably be a bit heavier, but also acceptable.